# how to update a value in firebase cloud firestore database using Cloud Functions for Firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to update cloud firestore database using cloud trigger functions but every time its throwing error in console

I already tried below code with no luck -

```
const ref = change.data().ref;
ref.update({
    "isVerified": true
});
```

This is my function -

```
exports.updateLisenceKey_SendEmailToOwner = functions.firestore
    .document('lisence_key/{userId}')
    .onUpdate((change, context) => {
       const ref = change.data().ref;
       ref.update({
           "isVerified": true
       });
    });
```

I expect the function should update node in cloud firestore database

Comment: What's the error you get?

Comment: @frankvanpuffelen ```   at exports.updateLisenceKey_SendEmailToOwner.functions.firestore.document.onUpdate (/srv/functions/index.js:198:28)```

Comment: @mufaddal_mw not enough

Comment: @ToraCode https://imgur.com/7RwtUOO

Comment: Above code may work in realtime database but its not working in firestore cloud database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After researching in firebase docs I found that its possible to update database from cloud firestore update trigger function using below code -

```
return change.after.ref.set({
          isVerified: true
        }, {merge: true});
```

Ref-
https://github.com/firebase/snippets-node/blob/9ae3a00985b53025fdc82716046882af71b6009d/firestore/extend-with-functions/functions/index.js#L108-L130

Comment: I have used same as above but not updating value in database